# 3 issues when scraping with selenium and python a)Certain elements not extracted b)How to use show to to display more info c)handling popups continous

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, popupwindow

website - [https://dir.indiamart.com/search.mp?ss=degreaser&mcatid=12735&catid=519&prdsrc=1&stype=attr=1|attrS&res=RC4](https://dir.indiamart.com/search.mp?ss=degreaser&mcatid=12735&catid=519&prdsrc=1&stype=attr=1%7CattrS&res=RC4)

1.Details like address,price,name,address not being extracted

```
degreaser_links = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//span[@class="elps elps2 p10b0 fs14 tac mListNme"]/a')))
# try:
#     close_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
#         EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='popup-close-button']"))
#     )
#     close_button.click()
# except Exception as e:
#     print("Failed to close the pop-up:", str(e))
for degreaser in degreaser_links:
    try:
        degreaser_links = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//span[@class="elps elps2 p10b0 fs14 tac mListNme"]/a')))
    #     current_degreaser=degreaser_links[index]
        degreaser.click()
        print(degreaser.text)
    except StaleElementReferenceException:
        degreaser_links = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//span[@class="elps elps2 p10b0 fs14 tac mListNme"]/a')))
        degreaser.click()
        print(degreaser.text)
    try:
        name= wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//h1[@class="bo center-heading"]')))
        names.append(name.text)
        print(name.text)
    except:
        names.append("NA")
    try:   
        price=wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//span[@class="prc-tip bo price-unit"]')))
        prices.append(price.text)
        print(price.text)
    except:
        prices.append("NA")
```

2.Use show more to display more  results
Html code for show more

```
<span class="dib fs15 br5 clr2 fwb bg3 cp"> Show More Results </span>
```

3.how to handle continuous popups?